# access check box private in Outlook Add-in

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

we are developing an Outlook Add-in and want to evaluate, if the user has checked the "private" box in the dialog:

[appointmentDialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wvOq.png)

We assume that this is the Office.context.mailbox.item.sensitivity API.
Are we right? The documentation states, that it is in preview.
What does this mean and when will it be availiable?

Reagards
Ulf

Answer (score 0):

The [Office.MailboxEnums.AppointmentSensitivityType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.mailboxenums.appointmentsensitivitytype?view=outlook-js-preview) enum contains all possible sensitivity types.

- Confidential = "confidential" - Treat the item as confidential.
- Normal = "normal" - The item needs no special treatment.
- Personal = "personal" - Treat the item as personal.
- Private = "private" - Treat the item as private.

```
// Link to full sample: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OfficeDev/office-js-snippets/prod/samples/outlook/99-preview-apis/calendar-properties-apis.yaml
Office.context.mailbox.item.sensitivity.getAsync(function(asyncResult) {
  if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
    console.log("Sensitivity: " + asyncResult.value);
  } else {
    console.log("Failed to get sensitivity: " + JSON.stringify(asyncResult.error));
  }
});
```

The preview means the API shouldn't be accessed in production. You can set up a testing environment in your lab for dev purposes, but the API is not widely available yet.

On the last Office Add-ins Community call was stated that a preview set will be  available in a production "soon", but not exact date was mentioned. I suspect it will be released next several months or so around the Build conference which takes place in the end of May.

Comment: Confirm this is the correct answer. This is slated to be shipped in 1.10 API Set.